# Sum instead of concatenate

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to increment input text value by 1 when clicked. It's a really simple task but i'm not able to make it working. Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#field').bind('click', function(){
    old_value = $(this).attr('value');
    $(this).attr('value', (old_value+1));
})
</script>
<form action="">
    <input type="text" value="1" id="field"/>
</form>
```

And after clicking on input, it's value is not incremented. Instead of that, number `1` is added at the end of the value so i.e. after 3 clicks the input value is `1111`. Have you any ideas what am i doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to typecast as all form values are passed around as strings.

```
$('#field').bind('click', function(){
    old_value = parseInt($(this).attr('value'), 10);
    $(this).attr('value', (old_value+1));
})
```

[Whatever you do don't forget to pass a radix (base) through to the parseInt function!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Octal_Interpretations_with_No_Radix)

If you forget, this might happen:

```
parseInt("010") # 8
```

Comment: +1 for stressing and explaining the importance of the radix parameter

Answer (score 2):

The unary `+` operator can conveniently turn a string into a number

```
$(this).attr('value', (+old_value + 1));
```

Or you can use `parseInt` like the other answers describe.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the string into a number:

```
parseInt($(this).val(), 10)
```