# parseInt() not working as expected

Tags: jquery, parseint

I am custom coding an image slider right now and I am adding a `data-slideNum` attribute to each slider image and thumbnail image like so:

```
$('.slide').each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr('data-slideNum',i);
});

$('.thumbnail').each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr('data-slideNum',i);
});
```

Of course this numbers the slides 0-X. Below the slider I would like to put a caption that shows what number slide you are on so I am trying to add `1` to the slide number variable and slide total so the numbers are correct:

```
$('.slideNum').html(parseInt(x+1)+' of '+parseInt(slideTotal+1));
```

The 2nd `parseInt()` is working correctly, but the first one is concatenating instead of parsing.

So instead of `2 of 5` I am getting `21 of 5` and so on.

Any ideas?

Comment: This behaviour means that the `x` value is a string. Can you expand your JS code example to show where you retrieve those values from.

Comment: Why the downvote? Anyway, thanks for all the responses, got it sorted out now!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sum instead of concatenate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9526126/sum-instead-of-concatenate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are performing string concatenation on `x` and `1`, and then taking the `int` value.

Essentially what you are doing is equivelent to:

```
var x = "2";
x = x + 1;
parseInt(x);
```

You can fix this by adding `1` to `x` after the `parseInt` call has returned an integer.

```
$('.slideNum').html( 
     ( parseInt(x, 10) + 1 ) 
     + ' of '
     + ( parseInt(slideTotal, 10) + 1 )
   ); // closes .html
```

In addition it is always a good idea to supply a radix to [**parseInt**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Also you don't need to add `1` to `slideTotal` if `slideTotal` is the length of the array, you also don't need to convert it to a `int`. So:

`$('.slideNum').html( ( parseInt(x, 10) + 1 ) + ' of ' + slideTotal);`

should suffice.

Comment: Thank you for the thoughtful answer, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.slideNum').html(parseInt(x+1)+' of '+parseInt(slideTotal+1));
```

is the issue

you are `parsing( x + 1 )` gives you a string first cause x is a string. then you're parsing that string to an integer...you should `parse(x)` then add 1 and you'll get it.

should be

```
$('.slideNum').html((parseInt(x) + 1) +' of '+parseInt(slideTotal+1));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are concatenating first, than trying to parse :

```
parseInt(x+1)
```

Where **x** is propably a String and your are concatenating it with 1 where you get 2 + 1 = 21 represented as string, and at the end you're just parsing 21 to an integer.

You have to parse **x** first, than do arithmetic eg :

```
parseInt(x) + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `parseInt(x) + 1` instead of `parseInt(x + 1)`. Concatenating a string and a number results in string concatenation.